# How to decrypt with crypto without errors

Tags: node.js, typescript, encryption, cryptojs

In NodeJS, I use the following functions to encrypt and decrypt strings. Strangely, it encrypts ok, it also decrypts ok but I still get an error:

> "ERR_OSSL_WRONG_FINAL_BLOCK_LENGTH"

What causes this error and what do I need to change to avoid this error?

```
export function encrypt(plainString:string) {
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
  let encrypted = Buffer.concat([cipher.update(Buffer.from(plainString, "utf8")), cipher.final()]);
  return encrypted.toString("base64");
}
```

```
export function decrypt(base64String:string) {
  const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv("aes-256-cbc", key, iv);
  const deciphered = Buffer.concat([decipher.update(Buffer.from(base64String, "base64")), decipher.final()]);
  return deciphered.toString("utf8");
}
```

Comment: When and where do you get that error? Can you edit your question and add the complete error message?

Comment: The issue is not reproducible, the code works, see online https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/LOq. Post non-productive sample data.